# What exception should I throw when expecting a null value?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, exception, entity, clean-architecture

Is there a standard [Exception](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.exception) to invoke when excepting null instead?

Commonly, exceptions are thrown for null references and arguments such as `NullReferenceException` and `ArgumentNullException` exceptions.

- The `NullReferenceException` is thrown when there is an attempt to dereference a null object reference.
- The `ArgumentNullException` is thrown when a null reference is passed to a method that does not accept it as a valid argument.

But what about in the event we expect the result to be null? For example, I am trying to validate if an entity exists in the database, if it does then **an exception should be thrown** and then I can log the error. The purpose of this validation is simply to ensure a duplicate entity is not created based on [Clean Architecture in ASP.NET Core](https://itechnolabs.ca/overview-of-clean-architecture-in-net-core).

The code is as follows:

```
private async Task ValidateEntityIfExist(EntityModel entityModel, CancellationToken cancellationToken)
{
    Entity entity = await this._repository.GetEntityByIdAsync(entityModel.Id, cancellationToken);
    if (entity != null)
    {
        throw new NotNullReferenceException($"{entityModel} with this id already exists.");
    }
}
```

I have tried to create a custom NotNullReferenceException class that inherits from Exception class which I use for logging the event:

The code is as follows:

```
public class NotNullReferenceException : Exception
{
    internal NotNullReferenceException(string message)
        : base(message)
    {
    }
    internal NotNullReferenceException(string message, Exception exception)
        : base(message, exception)
    {
    }
}
```

Is there a standard `Exception` to invoke when excepting `null` instead? If not, what would be the best solution or workaround to such a scenario?

---

### Update

Please note that this is based on Clean Architecture principles. For more information, [please visit this link](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/error-handling-in-clean-architecture-9ff159a25d4a).

Comment: I'd just use `InvalidOperationException`, although you could also consider `ArgumentOutOfRangeException` if this indicates a programmer error.

Comment: I would throw an ArgumentException. The definition of it is: 'The exception that is thrown when one of the arguments provided to a method is not valid.'

Comment: Best way here is create your own ValidationException and use it in all validation functions

Comment: `InvalidOperationException` is the best to use standard exception, when work is started, but can't be completed. Your method is trying to get something, it didn't worked as it should, throw.

Comment: If this method is part of your normal validation flow it should probably return a boolean (or custom Result object with  a Message and IsValid property) instead of an exception.

Comment: Doing separate checks runs the risk of race conditions. If you want to avoid duplicates it is typically better to add constraints to the DB. Then the database will throw an exception if you try to add a duplicate.

Comment: @lordvlad30 Yes, this is essentially the final result, however, based on Clean Architecture principles, errors from the Data Access/ Business Layer ought to be rethrown and handled from the Presentation Layer. We still need to account for and log the same https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deploying-web-site-projects/logging-error-details-with-asp-net-health-monitoring-cs. Inserting a duplicate record in a database will result in an exception, therefore we handle it at the Data layer, but at the UI layer we return the boolean value.

Comment: @MatthewWatson ArgumentOutOfRangeException seems out of scope

Comment: @ecemcy add a unique constraint on database level. And do a try-catch around the insert. Not really fan of doing an extra DB call if a Unique constraint on database level could solve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Clean Architecture, exceptions can be handled in a centralized spot to return consistent responses.

Once the business-level entities are defined, common exceptions and business-specific exceptions should be defined so that they can be shared among projects like API, Function App, Console App, etc..

Once the exceptions are defined, we need a centralized spot to handle all the pre-defined exceptions as well as the unknown exceptions (most likely a 500 error), log the errors, and then return a consistent API response so that any client that calls the API knows what to expect.

For example, in your case, we define an EntityAlreadyExistsException at the Core Layer as follows:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Text;

namespace MyApp.Core.Exceptions
{
    public class EntityAlreadyExistsException : Exception
    {
        public EntityAlreadyExistsException()
        { }

        public EntityAlreadyExistsException(string message) : base(message)
        { }

        public EntityAlreadyExistsException(string message, Exception inner) : base(message, inner)
        { }
    }
}
```

In order to catch all the exceptions, we can define a filter that runs asynchronously after an action has thrown an exception. For example:

```
using MyApp.Core.Exceptions;
using MyApp.WebAPI.Infrastructure.ApiExceptions;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.Filters;
using Serilog;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace MyApp.WebAPI.Infrastructure.Filters
{
    public class ApiExceptionFilterAttribute : ExceptionFilterAttribute
    {
        private readonly IDictionary<Type, Action<ExceptionContext>> _exceptionHandlers;

        public ApiExceptionFilterAttribute()
        {
            // Register known exception types and handlers.
            _exceptionHandlers = new Dictionary<Type, Action<ExceptionContext>>
            {
                { typeof(EntityAlreadyExistsException), HandleAlreadyExistsException }
            };
        }

        public override void OnException(ExceptionContext context)
        {
            HandleException(context);
            base.OnException(context);
        }

        private void HandleException(ExceptionContext context)
        {
            Log.Error(context.Exception, "Handling exception:");
            Type type = context.Exception.GetType();
            if (_exceptionHandlers.ContainsKey(type))
            {
                _exceptionHandlers[type].Invoke(context);
                return;
            }
            if (!context.ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                HandleInvalidModelStateException(context);
                return;
            }
            HandleUnknownException(context);
        }

        private void HandleAlreadyExistsException(ExceptionContext context)
        {
            EntityAlreadyExistsException exception = context.Exception as EntityAlreadyExistsException;
            ProblemDetails details = new ProblemDetails()
            {
                Type = "https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7231#section-6.5.4",
                Title = "The specified resource already exists.",
                Detail = exception.Message
            };
            context.Result = new NotFoundObjectResult(details);
            context.ExceptionHandled = true;
        }
    }
}
```

Then register the Filter:

```
services.AddControllers(options =>
  // handle exceptions thrown by an action
  options.Filters.Add(new ApiExceptionFilterAttribute())
);
```

You can find a Template to setup centralized exception handling and logging below:

https://github.com/ShawnShiSS/clean-architecture-azure-cosmos-db

Answer (score 2):

No one wants to be informed that something is not null and therefore exceptional. Someone wants to be informed if the entity with the given id already exists. So either throw a custom exception like `EntityExistsException` or don't use exceptions at all. Your method validates an entity, so why it does not return a `bool`?

Comment: You return bool after catching and logging the exception. Have a look at why it is important to implement Error Logging and health checks in following links https://livebook.manning.com/book/asp.net-core-security/chapter-11/v-11/ and https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-forms/overview/older-versions-getting-started/deploying-web-site-projects/logging-error-details-with-asp-net-health-monitoring-cs

Comment: @ecemcy: There is no need to throw an exception, you are calling a method which purpose is to give you the information if an entity is valid. I don't want to handle an exception, i just want to know if it's valid or not. That's a `bool`. What you do with that `bool` return value is your decision. You can log that you got an invalid entity for example. You would use exceptions if something is really unexpected or if you need to handle it in a much higher layer of your application.

Comment: To help you understand, consider this; if you insert a duplicate record in the database you trigger an `SqlException`. Validating before inserting any new record helps prevent this, but we still need to account for the exception that ought to have been thrown if we did not validate. We do this by logging an error when validating at the Business Logic layer. Important Note: We have to return `bool` ONLY THAT, in Clean Architecture we return the `bool` at the Presentation Layer after logging in subsequent layers. This is the best and recommended practice.

Answer (score 0):

No, there is no exception specifically for throwing on not null.

What you can do is either use `InvalidOperationException` (or any other passable built-in exception) or create your own Exception to throw.

I highly advise creating your own exception, as it can help differentiate between different error cases in your application.

When using `InvalidOperationException`, there is a chance that some built-in method will throw `InvalidOperationException` and your application will treat this completely different exception case the same as the database null check situation.

I'd go as far as to say that you should abstain from using built-in exceptions and should only throw your own custom exceptions, but at this point its about personal preference and perspective, so ill leave that for you to decide.